# How to do Minus HQL

Tags: database, oracle, hql

I have a table A{id, foo, ...} and a table B{id, boo, idA}
I want All objects in A that the ids doesn't appear in B

in Oracle SQL would looks like:

```
SELECT id FROM A MINUS( SELECT idA FROM B);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is easier than I supposed, I was focused in the minus

```
select a.id from A as a where a.id not in (select idA from B)
```

thanks

Comment: Pay attention.... if your B table has a lot of idA the query can be in error. (Oracle has a limit of 1000 rows, Sql Server 2500)

Comment: @JoeTaras, no. No, no, no - no! Nuh uh. Oracle does not have any "limit of 1000 rows". You are confusing this with the limit on the number of elements in an IN list of literals, e.g. `a.id not in (1,2,3,...)`

Answer (score 6):

MINUS function not exists in HQL, go [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) on paragraph 14.10 Expressions.

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'X' FROM B WHERE B.idA = A.id)
```

Comment: Does HQL allow the usage of the `EXCEPT` operator?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hi, on the link posted, not use EXCEPT. I use that link as a bible ;) (Another operator not used in HQL is UNION)

Comment: To be strictly equivalent to the `MINUS` query, you would need to add a `DISTINCT` - however, if `A.id` is unique then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Hi, I suppose ID field is primary key ;)